# How to display role name associated with user using rolify gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rolify

I have tables Roles, Users and Users_Roles. Each user will have a role associated with it. How to display the role name associated with a user in view.

index.html:

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= user.full_name %></td>
      <td><%= user.email %></td>
      <td class="text-center"><%= user.profile_name %></td>
      <td class="text-center"><%= user.client_list %></td></tr><% end %>
```

user.rb:

```
def profile_name
  Role.find(role_id).name
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add below method in model to get role of user

user.rb

```
def profile_name
 roles.collect(&:name).join(', ')
end
```

users_controller.rb

```
def index
 @users = User.includes(:roles)
end
```

In view, call role method as user.profile_name.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `role_id` in User. It's a "has and belongs to many" association, so users can have 0, 1 or many roles, it's how Rolify works.

If you are sure that users will only ever have exactly one role, you can do

```
def profile_name
  roles.first.name
end
```

If you allow no roles, then

```
def profile_name
  roles.first.try(&:name) || 'No role'
end
```

If you allow many roles, this could do

```
def profile_name
  roles.map(&:name).join(', ')
end
```